# Slow down jQuery draggable drag speed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is there anyway that i can slow down the "drag-speed" of a div? When i drag my current div i get really laggy results when dragging it vertically for some reason.

Slowing it down might make it a bit smoother?

This is my code is use to drag:

```
    $('#myDiv').bind('mouseover', function () {
        $(this).draggable({});
    });
```

Comment: Sorry updated code, its supposed to be $ :)

Comment: post a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem. Hard for anyone else to visualize without seeing it